# Program returns Incorrect eigenvalues

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, eigenvalue

The set of eigenvalues_new1 of (matnew1) and eigenvalues_new2 of
(matnew2) should give the square of the set of eigenvalues of (mat)..
But in this code I am getting negative eigenvalues for matnew1 and
matnew2..

Above all the square root(abs(eigenvalues_new1))  and
square root(abs(eigenvalues_new2)) are different from eigenvalues of the
matrix (mat) at least in case of one value.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import cmath
import math


for i in np.arange(1,2,1):
    MS = random.uniform(0.001,100)
    MD = random.uniform(1e-5,0.1)

    alpha = 0.5*((MD**2)/(MS**2))

    if(alpha < 0.01):
        mu = 1e-10
        MR = 1e+5

        mat = np.array([[0,0,MD],[0,mu,MS],[MD,MS,MR]])
        #print(mat)



        eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(mat)

        matDag = np.conjugate(np.transpose(mat))
        matnew1 = np.matmul(mat, matDag)



        matnew2 = np.matmul(mat,mat)
        #print(matnew1)
        #print(matnew2)
        eigenvalues_new1, eigenvectors_new1 = np.linalg.eig(matnew1)
        eigenvalues_new2, eigenvectors_new2 = np.linalg.eig(matnew2)


        print(eigenvalues[0],eigenvalues[1],eigenvalues[2])
        print(eigenvalues_new1[0],eigenvalues_new1[1],eigenvalues_new1[2])
        print(eigenvalues_new2[0],eigenvalues_new2[1],eigenvalues_new2[2])
```

Comment: For questions involving randomization please provide a seed for the random number generator for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this (you should have shown this output) I get:

```
100000.04370532616 7.718450571376183e-17 -0.043705325975408056
10000008741.067133 -4.0160149511470067e-14 0.0019101560620918938
10000008741.067133 -4.0160149511470067e-14 0.0019101560620918938
```

The second and third lines are very close to the square of the first:

```
In [5]: 0.0437**2                                                                                                                                             
Out[5]: 0.0019096900000000003

In [6]: 100000.043705**2                                                                                                                                      
Out[6]: 10000008741.001911
```

The negative entries are in the middle column and are approximately `-4e-14`. Since in the top row you have `7e-17` the second and third rows should the the square of that. However I would treat the `7e-17` as being either zero or all rounding error: really you have an eigenvalue close to zero. Likewise the `-4e-14` should be treated as zero.

Your matrix has this structure and this determinant:

```
In [18]: M                                                                                                                                                    
Out[18]: 
⎡0   0   MD⎤
⎢          ⎥
⎢0   μ   MS⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎣MD  MS  MR⎦

In [19]: M.det()                                                                                                                                              
Out[19]: 
   2  
-MD ⋅μ
```

Since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues and `mu` is very small the product of your eigenvalues needs to be small. That means that your large eignavlue has to be balanced by another very small one. Taken together that means that your matrix has a poor condition number and you can't expect to accurately compute the smaller eigenvalue.